# copy and paste the text in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

I have a graph in xmgrace (say, a graph of 10 different concentrations and hence 10 lines of different color), and I have typed some text corresponding to define what does each line represent. But now I have another similar graph and want to copy the same text typed for the previous graph to the new one.

How to copy and paste the text typed in the xmgrace from one graph to another.

Answer (score 2):

One of the frustrating things about using xmgrace is that it is not immediately obvious how to copy and paste.

You can copy selected text with `ctrl-insert` and paste it using `shift-insert`. This will work, for example, when editing the data set legend labels or axis labels.

However, if you do this many times it will become tedious. If you have already created a graph with labels you can re-use them all by saving a parameters file (a kind of template file).
To do this, with your first plot file loaded click 'Plot' > 'Save parameters' then choose a filename and click 'OK'.

You can then load the parameters file into any later plot. The parameters file contains lots of Graph, Set and Axis properties too.

Alternatively, when you are creating your second graph, add the `-param` flag to your command on the terminal.

e.g. `xmgrace -param /foo/bar/template.par data1.dat data2.dat`

Comment: It is possible to copy and paste text in xmgrace.

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to copy and paste text from clip board to xmgrace.

1. Copy the text to clipboard (the usual copy procedure).
2. Fire up xmgrace and take <kbd>windows</kbd> <kbd>drawing objects</kbd> <kbd>Text</kbd>.
3. Click on the `xmgrace` window where you want the text be shown. A window will popup, do `ctrl` + `shift` + `insert` to paste the copied text on the space provided for text.

Bonus (related) - If you want to break a single line, add the escape character at the possible end of line and add `\n`.